# Cannot deploy Azure backend resources in ADTLink for Unreal Engine Sample

Tags: unreal-engine4, azure-digital-twins

I was testing the [sample project](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-digital-twins-unreal-integration) demonstrating the Unreal Engine plug-in for Azure Digital Twins but I have a problem. In step 1 at the time of deploying the Azure resources it generates several errors and does not create the resource group. Could you help me with a solution?

They tell me that it may be an error in the cmd ./deployment/deploy/deploy.ps1

ERROR: {"code": "InvalidDeploymentParameterValue", "message": "The value of the deployment parameter 'appRegPassword' is null. Please specify the value or use the parameter reference. See https://aka.ms/resource-manager-parameter-files for details."}

Exception: /home/framework/azure-digital-twins-unreal-integration/deployment/deploy/deploy.ps1:456

Line |

456 | throw "Something went wrong with the deployment of the resource group ...

| ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

| something went wrong with the deployment of the resource pool. End of script.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues on that particular GitHub repository. It seems the deployment script is broken. You can try running the script with the changes in [this pull request](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-digital-twins-unreal-integration/pull/14). If that doesn't work, creating an issue on the repository will hopefully get you the help you need.